# Find and extract curr_id number from Investing

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to know the `curr_id` to submit using python to investing.com and extract historic data for a number of currencies/commodities. To do this I need the `curr_id` number. As in the example bellow. I'm able to extract all scripts. But then I cannot figure out how to find the correct script index that contains `curr_id` and extract the digits '2103'. Example: I need the code to find 2103.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-brl-historical-data'
r = requests.get(url)

#URL
url='http://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-brl-historical-data'
#OPEN URL
r = requests.get(url)
#DETERMINE FORMAT
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')

#FIND TABLE WITH VALUES IN soup
curr_data = soup.find_all('script', {'type':'text/javascript'})'
```

UPDATE
I did it like this:
    g_data_string=str(g_data)

```
if 'curr_id' in g_data_string: 
   print('success')

start = g_data_string.find('curr_id') + 9
end = g_data_string.find('curr_id')+13   

print(g_data_string[start:end])
```

But I`m sure there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression pattern](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) as a `text` argument to find a specific `script` element. Then, search inside the text of the `script` using the same regular expression:

```
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-brl-historical-data'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

pattern = re.compile(r"curr_id: (\d+)")
script = soup.find('script', text=pattern)

match = pattern.search(script.text)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

Prints `2103`.

Here `(\d+)` is a *capturing group* that would match one or more digits.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need a regex, you can get the id from by extracting the value attribute  from the input tag with the `name=item_ID`

```
In [6]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
In [7]: import  requests

In [8]: r = requests.get("http://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-brl-historical-data").content

In [9]: soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")

In [10]: soup.select_one("input[name=item_ID]")["value"]
Out[10]: u'2103'
```

You could also look for the id starting with `item_id`:

```
In [11]: soup.select_one("input[id^=item_id]")["value"]
Out[11]: u'2103'
```

Or look for the first div with the `pair_id` attribute:

```
In [12]: soup.select_one("div[pair_id]")["pair_id"]
Out[12]: u'2103'
```

There are actually numerous ways to get it.